# MobFox in Android - MobFoxView fails to instantiate

Tags: android

I am using MobFox with Android. I have a MobFoxView in one of my layouts. Runs fine when I compile the Android for 4.0.3. However, I wanted to try and build it for 2.0.1, and now it won't work.

On the visual editor I get the following error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
-  (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

In the error log I see:

```
com.mobfox.sdk.MobFoxView failed to instantiate.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mobfox.sdk.MobFoxView.<init>(MobFoxView.java:189)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
```

My MobFox view code is:

```
<com.mobfox.sdk.MobFoxView
            android:id="@+id/mobFoxView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            mode="live"
            publisherId="..." />
```

I'm importing the MobFox library through the .jar file. Runs fine when compiling for Android 4.0.3.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out be something completely unrelated: In the layout, I had two attributes in "match_parent", which is supported in Android 4 but not 2. Changing them to "fill_parent" allowed the files in the gen folder to be normally generated again and everything working.

Not a MobFox problem after all.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found out the answer less than 24h apart from posting the question and StackOverflow wouldn't let me mark it. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Your minimum build version should be the version used to build MobFox, but I couldn't see that on their web site without signing up. Set the target version (via the project>properties or `project.properties`) to `android-15` (or whatever), but in the `Android-Manifest.xml` specify the min sdk as 6 (or whatever) and target sdk as 15 (again, whatever). You need to be careful to limit yourself to the min version Android features.

Assuming this works and MobFox can be used in your lower version of Android, you could decrease the build API level and retest until it fails but in practice (IMO) if you want to be future proof you should keep the higher build API level and test against the minimum.

Note that `API 6` (2.0.1) has been marked obsolete and you'd be better off targeting `API 4` (android 1.6) or `API 7` (2.2)